# ASP.NET get bind object item in listview in file .aspx

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms

I have a listview with databind in it.

Now I can call each data of an object item in `<Itemtemplate></Itemtemplate>`. For example: `<%#Eval("id")%>`

But now I want to **get an object** of each `<Itemtemplate></Itemtemplate>`

Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the ListView's ItemDataBound event to capture the whole object for each data element. Following is the sample code on how you can do it. The ObjectTypeName is the class type of your object that you are trying to get.

```
protected void listView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Item.ItemType)
            {
                case ListViewItemType.DataItem:

                    var yourObject = e.Item.DataItem as ObjectTypeName;
                    break;
            }
        }
```